# Gitignore Multiple Square Bracketed Folders

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I'm currently trying to add gitignore to a json file that sits inside of two bracketed folders and one regular folder. I have tried multiple things to gitignore the file but it doesn't seem to work.

I've only been able to gitignore one bracketed file, is there a way to ignore a file that sits within multiple bracketed folders?
[paid-resources]/[snipes]/plants/plants.json

Comment: What is a "bracketed folder"?

Comment: See the example in the post above, folders that have brackets around them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` and `]` are special characters in `.gitignore` as they're part of `fnmatch/glob` syntax; see the section **File Name Patterns** in [`man sh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh). As they're special they must be escaped to be used literally. So try this pattern in `.gitignore`:

```
**/\[*\]/\[*\]/*
```

`**` start in any subdirectory;
`\[`, `\]` — interpret `[` and `]` literally;
`/\[*\]/\[*\]/` — two "bracketed" directories, one inside the other